# string.slice() not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am using `slice()`to take apart strings, but it does not work correctly.

strings:

```
var datept = "2018-01-19"
var timept = "12:05"
```

disjoint:

```
var month = datept.slice(5, -3); // should: "01" is: "01"
var day = datept.slice(8, -0); // should: "19" is: ""    --  WRONG
var year = datept.slice(0, -6); // should: "2018" is: "2018"
var hours = timept.slice(0, -3); // should: "12" is: "12"
var minutes = timept.slice(3, -0); // should: "05" is: "" -- WRONG
```

also tried:

```
var day = datept.slice(-8, -0); // or
var day = datept.slice(8, -0);  // or
var day = datept.slice(-8, 0);  // or
var day = datept.slice(8, 0);
```

[image: Debugged Code]

Comment: `splice !== slice`

Comment: He just got the title wrong Nina. No need to downvote

Comment: yeah, just spotted that too.

Comment: why dont you convert that string to a `Date` object? or even a `moment` object. then with the helper functions you could take the date hour and whatever you wanna do.

Comment: @slezica, i havn't dv.

Comment: Please provide code in text, not image.

Comment: All the nice people giving OP the advice to use a date object are correct... however, you're not explaining OP the real issue with his/her reasoning: `-0` is the same of `0`, as per the specs: *"If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
If x is −0 and y is +0, return true."* Therefore, `+0 === -0` is `true`.

Comment: The end result which you are expecting is a `Date` object?

Comment: @NinaScholz oops! sorry, saw the `-1` pop up at the same time as the comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split the date and use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the values.

```js
var datept = "2018-01-19",
    timept = "12:05",
    [year, month, day] = datept.split('-'),
    [hours, minutes] = timept.split(':');
    
console.log(year, month, day);
console.log(hours, minutes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `-0`. I'm not even sure what that's supposed to mean :) `-0` is just `0`, and `slice` will be confused by `endIndex` being lower than `startIndex`.

Here:

```
var day = datept.slice(8, -0); // should: "19" is: ""    --  WRONG
```

Instead:

```
var day = datept.slice(8); // should: "19" is: "19"
```

Anyway, there's better ways of doing this. You could manipulate a `Date` object (though those are not exactly intuitive), or use `split()` to get the fragments instead:

```
> var parts = "2018-01-19".split("-")
> parts[0] // '2018'
> parts[1] // '01'
> parts[2] // '19'
```

Using modern javascript, you can even:

```
> const [ year, month, day ] = "2018-01-19".split("-")
> year  // '2018'
> month // '01'
> day   // '19'
```

Comment: There is `-0` in IEEE 754, you can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: I know :) but I don't think floating-point representation at CPU register level is really relevant for this case

Answer (score 1):

Why not using string.split()?

```
let str = "2018-01-19";
let parts = str.split("-");
let day = parts[2];
let month = parts[1];
let year = parts[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution its simply stupid. Why won't you convert to a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object (native) or even a use [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) (you will have to import it) and then get what you want with the help of `helper` functions?

```
let c = new Date("2018-01-19")
c.getDate() // 19
c.getMonth() + 1 // 0 (its from 0-11)
```

and soo on. See more documentation for each on highlights.

Comment: Sorry Nicholas, but I downvoted this answer because saying something is **stupid** never helped anyone.

Comment: NP @slezica, it will help him in the future :D